# Detect fullscreen mode in Qt on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, fullscreen

I need to know if my application is in a fullscreen mode.
Fullscreen mode is activated by the following code:

```
myWidgetPtr->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
myWidgetPtr->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
myWidgetPtr->show();
myWidgetPtr->activateWindow();
```

Fullscreen mode itself works fine.
Then I'm trying to detect it using the following code:

```
if (QApplication::activeWindow() && QApplication::activeWindow()->isFullScreen())
{
// handle fullscreen mode here
}
```

This solution do the job on Linux, but on Mac OS X (10.10.5), `QApplication::activeWindow()` always returns 0. So, I am not able to detect fullscreen mode.

Also I've tried to do this check using Objective-C code:

```
bool isAppInFullscreen()
{
    NSWindow *activeWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    return (activeWindow.styleMask & NSFullScreenWindowMask);
}
```

But unfortunately It does not work either.
I am using Qt 4.8.7.

Comment: By the time I used a boolean to store my state because I didn't trust Qt...

Comment: Tried upgrading to Qt 5? As of 2016, Qt 4 is unsupported.